# A trigger to update one column value to equal the pkid of the record

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to write a trigger that will set the value in  column 2 = to the value in column 1 after a record has been created.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
create trigger update_docindex2_to_docid
ON dbo.TABLENAME
after insert
AS BEGIN
 set DOCINDEX2 = DOCID     
END;
```

I answered my own question one I sat and thought about it long enough....

This seems way to simple. I'm concerned that I'm going break something because I don't have a where condition that would identify the correct record. I want this to update docindex2 to the newly created DOCID after a record is created in the database. The docid is the pkid.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (docid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, docindex2 INT);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_mytrigger
ON Table1 AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE t
   SET t.docindex2 = t.docid
  FROM Table1 t JOIN INSERTED i
    ON t.docid = i.docid;

INSERT INTO Table1 (docindex2) VALUES(0), (0);
```

Contents of Table after insert

```
| DOCID | DOCINDEX2 |
---------------------
|     1 |         1 |
|     2 |         2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a352/1)** demo